# Set a specific Time duration for page

Tags: php

I would like to specify the duration of the display of a form. Suppose there is a variable with the value `x=(10)`, whenever I call this page, the timer should be based on the current time and the form should be displayed for 10 minutes and after this time the form should be sent automatically.

```
<?php 
 include 'db_conn.php';
 if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $var=$_GET['id'];
$query="SELECT * FROM addquiz WHERE quz_id='$var' ";
$db=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$res=mysqli_fetch_array($db);
$noquestions=$res['noquestion'];
$quiz=$res['title'];
}?>

<div class="container">
<form  method="POST" class="form-horizontal" >

<div style="margin-left: 30%;"><b>Your Quiz: &nbsp; &nbsp; <?php echo $quiz;?></b> &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; 
<input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" style="height: 30px; width: 30%;"></div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="panel" style="margin:5%">

<?php 
$count=1;
$que="SELECT * FROM addques WHERE quz_id='$var'";
$dbd=mysqli_query($conn,$que);
    while ($cmd=mysqli_fetch_array($dbd)) {

            $quest=$cmd['qusname'];
            $ans_id=$cmd['ans_id'];
            $opt1=$cmd['qpta'];
            $opt2=$cmd['optb'];
            $opt3=$cmd['optc'];
            $opt4=$cmd['optd'];
            $answ=$cmd['answer'];?>
<b>Question &nbsp; <?php echo $count++;?>&nbsp;:<br><?php echo $quest;?></b><br><br>
<fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="ansid[]" value="<?php echo $ans_id; ?>">
<input type="checkbox" name="ans[]" value="1"><?php echo $opt1;?><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ans[]" value="2"><?php echo $opt2;?><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ans[]" value="3"><?php echo $opt3;?><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ans[]" value="4"><?php echo $opt4?><br><br><br>
</fieldset>
<?php } ?>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
<div class="button" style="margin-left: 60%;"> <a href="result.php?name=<?php echo $_POST['user_name'];?>"  class="btn btn-info">View Result </a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div> 
<?php
$i=0;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name=$_POST['user_name'];
while ( $i<$noquestions  ) { 
$query="INSERT INTO `result`(  `quz_id`, `ans_id`, `answer`,`user_name`) VALUES('";
$query.=$var .  "', '"; 
$query.=$_POST['ansid'][$i] .  "', '"; 
$query.=$_POST['ans'][$i] .   "', '";
$query.=$name .   "' )";


$db=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$i++;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You need JavaScript for that. Once PHP sends its data to the client, its finished executing.

Comment: `setTimeout(function () {$('#form').submit()}, x * 60 * 1000)`

Comment: If you are trying to do timed quiz, know that javascript code can be altered by the users. They can basically cheat and send the form **after** the 10 minutes timeout. You have to check the elapsed time server-side with php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

As you say "at each visit of the page" it could be done like this with javascript:

```
window.onload = function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        document.form.submit();
    }, 5000);
};
```

Further you could set the timeout from your php variable and like the comment says above, you could validate the taken time on the server side with php to make sure no one is cheating.